# Android Design Application

Tags: android, android-design-library

I here attached some snap here.
I am very new in android so any give idea for create the design or give any link to learn design

[image: asdf]

Comment: Please specify your question. Do you want to know how to design an app, or do you want to know which patterns you could use to achieve this design?

Comment: Learn to use RecyclerView with an RecyclerViewAdapter for the list. That's probably a vertical LinearLayout with a TextView and an EditText/Spinner for the list item. The bottom part is a BottomNavigationView. Hope this is enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

There are lots of beginner courses for Android design. You can try this link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the Android Material Design guidelines

https://material.io/ 
https://material.io/guidelines/